# Redirect to Passcode Settings directly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can redirect to the "Settings" in an iOS app using the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

I'm trying to redirect specifically to the "Touch ID & Passcode" settings within the settings.  Is there a way to do this?  Assume that the device is capable of Passcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only open your apps settings bundle or the system 'root' settings.

I have found a blog post that seems to describe what you want, but when I tried it I had no luck, maybe if you persist a bit it will for you.

http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/open-settings-directly-from-your-app/

Answer (score 1):

Apple changes the way to open specific menu in Settings. The value of scheme for iOS 10 is ***"App-Prefs:"***. But maybe it will be changed in next versions.

You can try to open different URLs in a cycle.
Remember that the constant *UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString* is not defined in iOS 7 (if you support this version).

Please take a look on my code. It works on iOS 10 and lower versions.

```
// UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString is available since iOS 8.0
NSString * defaultSettingsStr = ( &UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL ? UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString : @"prefs:root" );

// Array of possible URLs, differ in various iOS versions
NSArray * urlStrs = @[@"App-Prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE",
                 @"Prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE",
                 defaultSettingsStr];

for (NSString * urlStr in urlStrs) {
   NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
       // openURL is deprecated since iOS 10
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: its not opening specific menu in setting, its just open settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can directly open particular settings in iOS.
prefs:root and App-Prefs:root both are blocked by apple.

If you use this anyway apple will reject your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. iOS only allows redirection to the settings of your specific app.